# Get array from BackgroundTask method to another Activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity

I'm newbie in Java/ADT and I'm trying to get an array from "Activity A" to "Activity B". The app takes information from a webpage, and then saves it in a pair of arrays and show the information. I want to click a "go to graph" button (calls to viewallday()) to redirect to Activity B who will show a graphic with all this information.

The problem is that they're a self refresh array (1sec refresh) and don't want to loose this feature when the app It's on graphic mode (Activity B). Any ideas about how to do that?

Thank all of you in advance, I'm learning a lot from this site.

**UPDATE**: I'm trying to do this with a Singleton pattern. But LogCat says:

02-26 22:21:59.300: E/AndroidRuntime(2677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 22:21:59.300: E/AndroidRuntime(2677): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Chispa/com.example.Chispa.Activity_allday}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-26 22:21:59.300: E/AndroidRuntime(2677): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

**UPDATE 2:** Finally got it!! Here's the code I used:

Here's the code for Activity A:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView tvmax, tvmid, tvmin, tvactualval,tvvaloractual,tvdate;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
        tvvaloractual=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvvaloractual);
        tvmax=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvmaximo);
        tvmid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvmedio);
        tvmin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvminimo);

        new BackGroundTask().execute();

        callAsynchronousTask();

    }


    public void callAsynchronousTask() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {       
                        try {
                            BackGroundTask performBackgroundTask = new BackGroundTask();
                            // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that extends AsynchTask 
                            performBackgroundTask.execute();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000); //execute in every 1000 ms
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class Pair
    {
        public String[] bar;
        public String[] values;
    }

       public void viewallday(View view) {



            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_allday.class);


            startActivity(intent);



        }  





    class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }



        public String[] getValuesGraph(Document doc) {


                int cont=24,var=7;
                String bar[] = new String[cont];



               /*
                * Getting elements from the graphic in an array from 0-23. 0 it's 1:00am, 23 it's 00:00am
                */

               for (cont=0; cont < 24; cont++){

               String onMouseOver = doc.select("a").get(var+cont).attr("onMouseOver");
               bar[cont] = onMouseOver.split("'")[9];


               }


               return bar;



        }



        public String[] getValuesFooter(Document doc) {



            String values[] = new String[7];


            /*
                * Getting elements from the graphic footer
                */

               String delimiters= "[ /]+";
               Elements elements = doc.select("td.cabeceraRutaTexto");
               elements.size(); // 6



                   /*  Getting text from table */
                   values[0] = elements.get(0).text(); // TITLE
                   values[1] = elements.get(1).text(); // TEXT MAX VALUE
                   values[2] = elements.get(2).text(); // TEXT MIDDLE VALUE
                   values[3] = elements.get(3).text(); // TEXTO MIN VALUE

                   /* Getting numbers from table */

                   values[4] = elements.get(4).text().split(delimiters)[0]; // NUMBER MAX VALUE
                   values[5] = elements.get(5).text().split(delimiters)[0]; // NUMBER MIDDLE VALUE
                   values[6] = elements.get(6).text().split(delimiters)[0]; // NUMBER MIN VALUE    


                   return values;


         }


        public Document getUrl(){

              try {
                    URL url= new URL("http://www.endesaonline.com/canal/precios/Canal_Preciosdelpool.asp?FECHA=20140226");
                    /*URL url= new URL("http://www.endesaonline.com/canal/precios/Canal_Preciosdelpool.asp?lang=es&frameId=4064&segmento=1&promocion=");*/
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();

                    return doc;      

              } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Pair doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Pair p = new Pair();


                GlobalVariables gs = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
                gs.setBar(getValuesGraph(getUrl()));

                p.bar = getValuesGraph(getUrl());

                p.values = getValuesFooter(getUrl());


         return p;


        }



        public String ActualHourValue() {

            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("H");
            String onlyhour = formatter.format(new Date());

            return onlyhour;


        }

        public void ShowDateHour(){


            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
            String formattedDate3 = df3.format(c.getTime());
            tvdate.setText("Fecha y hora actuales : "+formattedDate3);

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Pair p) {



            int hour =  Integer.parseInt(ActualHourValue());
            tvvaloractual.setText(p.bar[hour]+" €/MWh");

            tvmax.setText(p.values[4]+" €/MWh");
            tvmid.setText(p.values[5]+" €/MWh");
            tvmin.setText(p.values[6]+" €/MWh");

            ShowDateHour();

           /*super.onPostExecute(p.values);*/
        }





    }




}
```

And here's the code for Activity B:

```
public class Activity_allday extends MainActivity {


private TextView tvall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_day_price);

        TextView tvall=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvall); 

        GlobalVariables gs = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
        String[] s = gs.getBar();
        tvall.setText(s[0]);       

    }
```

}

And here's a GlobalVariable class who captures the array I want to send to Activity B:

```
public class Activity_allday extends MainActivity {


private TextView tvall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_day_price);

        TextView tvall=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvall); 

        GlobalVariables gs = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
        String[] s = gs.getBar();
        tvall.setText(s[0]);       

    }
```

}

That's all! hope It'll help to future users.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: have you tried having a service that saves the data to some shared place (application singleton, for example)?

Comment: Nope, I'll take a look on Google about singleton and his application on my prob.

Thank you very much @Stephan

Comment: You can also use parcels. See [Parcel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) for more info.

Comment: @Stephan Finally I'm trying to use singleton. The call to Activity B works fine, but when I try to get the array, program crashes with the above error. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: @user3321425, sorry, I was off a few days. I see you managed anyway. Could you post your solution as an answer so that others may benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could try:

Inside your AsyncTask, define an interface and a method inside it that will pass back the data to the calling activity and inside that method, call the next activity and set the data as an extra.

This is the simplest way.

In your AsyncTask, inside onPostExecute(result), use a try block to call the method which belongs to the above mentioned interface which must be implemented by the calling activity.

**HomeActivity.java**

```
/public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements SampleAsyncTask.OnUpdateListener{

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     executeAsync();
 }

 public void executeAsync(){

     new SampleAsyncTask(this).execute("someFlagToCheck");
 }

 @Override
 public void onDataProcessed(String result){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("data", result);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

**SampleAsyncTask.java**

```
public class SampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    Context context;

    //constructor
    SampleAsyncTask(Context context){
       this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void doInBackground(String... params){

         //do something depending on the arguments in params
         return "data";
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result){

        try{
           ((OnUpdateListener) context).onDataProcessed(result);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public interface OnUpdateListener{

        public void onDataProcessed(String data);
    }
}
```

Follow this example. The calling activity implements the AsyncTask's interface and overrides its method which will be called when the async task is done with the result.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you @Eenvincible. I'm going to read carefully what you recommend to try to reproduce it.  I'm fighting over this problem and all I've got for now is a loop of calls to startActivity. :P

Comment: It worked, but causes a loop too because if I put the activity call inside the onPostExecute(), the method it's calling indefinitely  startActivity(intent); @Eenvincible

Thanks again.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately your answer doesn't solve my problem yet. As I explain in my previous comment, I've got a loop with startActivity(intent) because the BackGroundTask and by extension his method OnPostExecute() refreshes every second.@Eenvincible

If you could give me a sample code It would be very helpful. 
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to fit your lines in my code. But there's something wrong with Asynctask, callAsynchronousTask, BackGroundTask and with public interface OnUpdateListener (something about it must be defined on top level class). I'll take a look tomorrow, now I must rest. Thank you @Eenvincible !!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make the code work properly, I'll keep trying. Maybe the way I've picked vars It's not the best to send them to Activity_allday @Eenvincible.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

Here's the code for Activity A:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView tvmax, tvmid, tvmin, tvactualval,tvvaloractual,tvdate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
    tvvaloractual=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvvaloractual);
    tvmax=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvmaximo);
    tvmid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvmedio);
    tvmin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvminimo);

    new BackGroundTask().execute();

    callAsynchronousTask();

}


public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        BackGroundTask performBackgroundTask = new BackGroundTask();
                        // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that extends AsynchTask 
                        performBackgroundTask.execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000); //execute in every 1000 ms
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class Pair
{
    public String[] bar;
    public String[] values;
}

   public void viewallday(View view) {



        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_allday.class);


        startActivity(intent);



    }  





class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }



    public String[] getValuesGraph(Document doc) {


            int cont=24,var=7;
            String bar[] = new String[cont];



           /*
            * Getting elements from the graphic in an array from 0-23. 0 it's 1:00am, 23 it's 00:00am
            */

           for (cont=0; cont < 24; cont++){

           String onMouseOver = doc.select("a").get(var+cont).attr("onMouseOver");
           bar[cont] = onMouseOver.split("'")[9];


           }


           return bar;



    }



    public String[] getValuesFooter(Document doc) {



        String values[] = new String[7];


        /*
            * Getting elements from the graphic footer
            */

           String delimiters= "[ /]+";
           Elements elements = doc.select("td.cabeceraRutaTexto");
           elements.size(); // 6



               /*  Getting text from table */
               values[0] = elements.get(0).text(); // TITLE
               values[1] = elements.get(1).text(); // TEXT MAX VALUE
               values[2] = elements.get(2).text(); // TEXT MIDDLE VALUE
               values[3] = elements.get(3).text(); // TEXTO MIN VALUE

               /* Getting numbers from table */

               values[4] = elements.get(4).text().split(delimiters)[0]; // NUMBER MAX VALUE
               values[5] = elements.get(5).text().split(delimiters)[0]; // NUMBER MIDDLE VALUE
               values[6] = elements.get(6).text().split(delimiters)[0]; // NUMBER MIN VALUE    


               return values;


     }


    public Document getUrl(){

          try {
                URL url= new URL("http://www.endesaonline.com/canal/precios/Canal_Preciosdelpool.asp?FECHA=20140226");
                /*URL url= new URL("http://www.endesaonline.com/canal/precios/Canal_Preciosdelpool.asp?lang=es&frameId=4064&segmento=1&promocion=");*/
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();

                return doc;      

          } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Pair doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Pair p = new Pair();


            GlobalVariables gs = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
            gs.setBar(getValuesGraph(getUrl()));

            p.bar = getValuesGraph(getUrl());

            p.values = getValuesFooter(getUrl());


     return p;


    }



    public String ActualHourValue() {

        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("H");
        String onlyhour = formatter.format(new Date());

        return onlyhour;


    }

    public void ShowDateHour(){


        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
        String formattedDate3 = df3.format(c.getTime());
        tvdate.setText("Fecha y hora actuales : "+formattedDate3);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Pair p) {



        int hour =  Integer.parseInt(ActualHourValue());
        tvvaloractual.setText(p.bar[hour]+" €/MWh");

        tvmax.setText(p.values[4]+" €/MWh");
        tvmid.setText(p.values[5]+" €/MWh");
        tvmin.setText(p.values[6]+" €/MWh");

        ShowDateHour();

       /*super.onPostExecute(p.values);*/
      }





    }


  }
```

Activity B:

```
public class Activity_allday extends MainActivity {


private TextView tvall;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_day_price);

    TextView tvall=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvall); 

    GlobalVariables gs = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
    String[] s = gs.getBar();
    tvall.setText(s[0]);       

}
```

}

Global variable class who captures the array I want to send to Activity B:

```
public class Activity_allday extends MainActivity {


private TextView tvall;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_day_price);

    TextView tvall=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvall); 

    GlobalVariables gs = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
    String[] s = gs.getBar();
    tvall.setText(s[0]);       

}
}
```

Thanks all for your help!!